# Avoiding purple anomaly on imagery in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, imagery

What is this purple anomaly on the imagery that we just received?

The only thing I have done processing wise is to build the pyramids when they first came into ArcMap. Other than that, I have not done anything.

I also should add that the purple disappears when zoomed in to an extent past 1:10000, and gets larger as you zoom out.

[image]

Comment: Could it be something to do with the rgb colours?, and for anyone who needs clarification, it is a TIFF image. Thanks...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would certainly go back to the original image and try rebuilding the pyramids.  The fact that it disappears when zooming in to me means it's a pyramid issue.  If it persists in ArcMap, do as @scw says, and try GDAL.

Comment: Thanks for that. Re-building the pyramids gave me a much cleaner image, and everything looks great.

Answer (score 3):

I can't specifically address why ArcGIS overviews are creating the purple block, but perhaps try creating overviews with `GDAL` on a copy of the file, and see if the artifact persists:

```
gdaladdo --config USE_RRD YES input.tif 2 4 8 16
```

Comment: I also tried this process, and it worked as well, so thanks!!